# Nice command in .sh script for Cron Jobs

Tags: php, apache, bash, cron, nice

I have this php script that I need to run on shared webhosting.
I have created a cron job that executes an sh script. The command for the cron was:

`/bin/sh /home/user/script.sh`

So I'm assuming it is Bourne Shell (or something compatible). The script itself was:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/user/public_html/folder/
#updating DB
php -q ./run_interactive_job.php batch_control_files/updateDB
echo Updated DB results
```

**My question is**:
Can I add **Nice** priorities to the php command ? Or do I need to add it to the script at the cron command. Which one is more likely to work ?

`nice 10 php -q ./run_interactive_job.php batch_control_files/updateDB`

**Would that be successful at running at a lower priority.**

**PS:** Basically, this script has overloaded the server before when I ran it through the browser and it affected apache on that server resulting in my hosts blocking the file. I have repeatedly asked them unblock to test it with different parameters. And Now I'm trying to run it through cron at a lower priority in the hopes that it won't affect apache. But I don't want it to create issues again, hence I'm trying to use **NICE**

If anyone has any other suggestion that would offer a similar solution of running the php script without affecting apache or the webserver, that'sgreat too.

Answer (score 6):

skip the shell script and use

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/nice -n 10 /path/php -q /path/script.php
```

nice and\or php path may or may not be required

Comment: I do wish to add additional commands to the script as well. I have to run a couple more php scripts and empty a few sql tables before I run any php.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I asked this question in two places as I thought I wasn't getting a response.
I asked at Superuser and I received an answer that suits my needs.

@Dagon - The answer from Dagon would seem to work as well and I will provide an update when I have resolved this issue with either solutions.

[The same Question asked at Superuser - https://superuser.com/questions/537509 ...](https://superuser.com/questions/537509/nice-commands-in-a-sh-script-for-cron-jobs)

UPDATE: I used the batch file as shown there. I used the nice command before php inside the batch file. The only difference being:

`nice -n 10 php -q ./run_interactive_job.php batch_control_files/updateDB`

I added more commands to run additional php scripts with the same nice property to them. They all worked great.

THANKS EVERYONE FOR THE INPUT

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine.  If you put the `nice` in the Cron job itself, it will affect the priority of the entire job; but since the script only contains one command whose priority it really makes sense to set, doing it inside the script works just as well in practice.